# Beacon prefill function

Tags: javascript, beacon

I already set up the Beacon 'identify' stuffs, and can open up using `Beacon("open");`

But when I try to use `prefill` function, i'm getting some error.

```
Beacon("prefill", {
    name: "Steve Aoki",
    email: "steve@aoki.com",
    subject: "Need help with invoice",
    text: "Hello, I need some help with my invoice. See attached.."
})
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`
Any code that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Reference [here](https://developer.helpscout.com/beacon-2/web/javascript-api/#beaconprefill-formobject)

Comment: I think you need a `fields` array.

Comment: @JackBashford you're right I need to put  `fields:[]` (even empty) to make it work. It's a `must have` docu should say it haha. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `fields` array, because in the example you posted, the one thing your code doesn't have is a `fields` array. This is also shown because `filter` is an array method, and calling `fields.filter` when you don't have `fields` will result in an `undefined` error.